# Change Text color when hovered over a link in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to change the colour of the text when hovered over a link in QLabel. I couldn't achieve it using the label provided by PyQt, So I am trying to create a custom label by inheriting QLabel.

Here is the code I have tried, but this doesn't work properly:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class LinkLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, link=""):
        super(LinkLabel, self).__init__()

        self.setText('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" style="color: black; font: 14px; text-decoration: None;">'
                                 'StackOverflow</a>')

        self.setFixedSize(100, 50)
        # self.linkHovered.connect(lambda : print("Hovered"))
        self.linkActivated.connect(self.reDirect)
        #self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def reDirect(self, linkStr):
        QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl(linkStr))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print(self.fontMetrics().boundingRect("StackOverflow"), event.pos())
        if self.fontMetrics().boundingRect("StackOverflow").contains(event.pos()):
            print("Hovered")
            self.setText('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" style="color: blue; font: 14px; text-decoration: None;">'
                      'StackOverflow</a>')

        else:
            self.setText('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" style="color: black; font: 14px; text-decoration: None;">'
                         'StackOverflow</a>')

        super(LinkLabel, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    # def enterEvent(self, event):
    #     print("YES", self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(self.text()))
    #     if self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(self.text()).contains(event.pos()):
    #         print("Hovered")
    #         self.setText('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" style="color: blue; font: 14px;">'
    #                   'SignUp</a>')
    #         # self.fontMetrics().tightBoundingRect()
    #     super(LinkLabel, self).enterEvent(event)
    #
    # def leaveEvent(self, event):
    #     if not self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(self.text()).contains():
    #         self.setText('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" style="color: black; font: 14px;">'
    #                      'SignUp</a>')
    #
    #     super(LinkLabel, self).leaveEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout().addWidget(LinkLabel())


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win =MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I did try `QLabel.linkHovered.connect()` but the problem was that once hovered it would change the colour and wouldn't reset back to the original colour. Comment parts are all the things I tried.

Comment: Is the label going to show just a link?

Comment: @musicamante yes, but I don't want the link to change colour when the mouse cursor is inside the label boundary. I want it to change only if the mouse is over the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work properly because the label is centered, while your call to [`boundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect) obviously isn't:

> Returns the rectangle that is covered by ink if character ch were to be drawn **at the origin of the coordinate system**.

Moreover, you're using a bigger font, and fontMetrics couldn't know anything about that, since it's based on the widget's `font()`.

The solution is to use the correct [boundingRect()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2) implementation with a constructed font metrics based on the font you're going to use:

```
    def checkHover(self, pos=None):
        if pos is None:
            pos = self.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        font = self.font()
        font.setPixelSize(14)
        fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
        textRect = fm.boundingRect(self.rect(), self.alignment(), "StackOverflow")
        self.setText('''
            <a href="{link}" style="color: {color}; font: 14px; text-decoration: None;">
            {alias}</a>'''.format(
                link='https://stackoverflow.com', 
                alias='StackOverflow', 
                color='blue' if pos in textRect else 'black', 
            ))

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.checkHover()
        super(LinkLabel, self).enterEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.checkHover(event.pos())
        super(LinkLabel, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.checkHover()
        super(LinkLabel, self).leaveEvent(event)
```

Note that I used `setPixelSize()` because you set the font size in pixels, while you should better use points instead, as they would be device independent (which is the preferred practice for font rendering).

Comment: isn't `fontMetrics()` equivalent to `font = self.font() font.setPixelSize(14)  fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)` as the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) states?

Comment: @JacksonPro no: changing the font properties in the label's text doesn't change the widget's font. The `fontMetrics()` returns the metric for the current font, which is the default of the application. If you plan on always using the same font properties, then don't set it in the label text, but call `setFont()` with the font you want to use, and `fontMetrics()` will then return the correct metrics.

Comment: One more question using `.setPointSizeF()` doesn't change anything. Is it supposed to be used with the style sheet? This is how I used it (note: I removed the font from the style in setText()) -> `font = self.font() font.setPointSizeF(30.23) self.setFont(font)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't change anything"? Change what? Where do you use it, and how? What should "Is it supposed to be used with the style sheet" mean? Please, make yourself clear!

Comment: `.setPointSizeF()` doesn't change the font size. I replaced `font.setPixelSize(14)` with `font.setPointSizeF(12.2)` I am not sure whether this is the right method. I used it as you advised me to use points instead of pixels and the only method I found that suited what you advised was `setPointSize` I might be wrong idk.

Comment: Sorry but your comment doesn't clarify anything, you're just repeating what you've said in the previous comment, while I asked other specific questions. If you don't explain *exactly* what you're doing, it's impossible to help. Find a way to clarify or at least put some MRE in an accessible gist/pastebin.

Comment: 1) Please don't update the question with something related to an answer, it makes your post confusing; I explictly suggested you to use a pastebin or a gist to do so. 2) Do you realize you're still using the font size in the html text? Please, be more careful with your editings, and ensure that you understand what the code shown to you actually does, as this is not the first time you ignore that fundamental aspect. 3) You can't access the layout of a QMainWindow, use `setCentralWidget()`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know what Pastebin was. "Do you realize you're still using the font size in the HTML text" I didn't notice that when I was posting it here, but I did try removing font size from HTML text. I didn't get your 3rd point (more specifically where did I try to access the layout of QMainWindow). Here is the link to Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/mGdEzdtk

Comment: 1) As explained, once the font is set on the widget, there's no need to create a new QFontMetrics instance as long as the text in the label doesn't use different font settings; 1b) It's better to set the text *after* setting the font; 2) The `checkHover` function should match the contents of the text (I obviously used hardcoded values in my example), you didn't; 3) In your code you're using `self.layout().addWidget(LinkLabel())`, which is wrong for a QMainWindow; 4) Read and *carefully study* this corrected code by understanding how it works, what it does and how: https://pastebin.com/f6R5YGQ4